# Cannot loop in the next dictionary in a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list of three dictionaries:

```
[{'name': 'C:\\2.jpg.npy', 'vidname': 'P0004_T00', 'tensor': tensor([[-6.0413e-02]], dtype=torch.float64)},
 {'name': 'C:\\2.jpg.npy', 'vidname': 'P0004_T00', 'tensor': tensor([[-6.0413e-02]], dtype=torch.float64)}, 
{'name': 'C:\\4.jpg.npy', 'vidname': 'P0005_T00', 'tensor': tensor([[-6.0413e-02]], dtype=torch.float64)}]
```

I want just one entry for each vidname hence I am using torch stack to stack the tensors, so I will have the following list of two dictionaries:

```
[{'name': 'C:\\2.jpg.npy', 'vidname': 'P0004', 'tensor': tensor([[-6.0413e-02]], dtype=torch.float64)}, 
{'name': 'C:\\3.jpg.npy', 'vidname': 'P0005', 'tensor': tensor([[-6.0413e-02]], dtype=torch.float64)}]`
```

I tried the following function:

```
def stack_tensors(data):
   
    dictlist = data
    mainlist =[]
    mdict = {}
    stacktensor = []

    xcount = 0
    for samples in dictlist:
        if xcount == 0: 
            prevsample = samples
            xcount+=1
        else:
            if samples['vidname'] == prevsample['vidname']:
                 stacktensor.append(samples['tensor'])
                 
                 prevsample = samples
                 
            if samples['vidname'] != prevsample['vidname']:
                  
                  name2video = str(prevsample['name2video'])
                  print('name2video', name2video)
                  
                  mdict['name'] = prevsample['name2video']
                  mdict['tensor'] = torch.stack(stacktensor)
                  prevsample = samples
                  dict_copy = mdict.copy()
                  mainlist.append(dict_copy)
```

but it only prints the first dictionary. The loop ends there.

Comment: Your question would be better with a [mre] - especially the data should be made minimal, scanning these monsters for differences ... well, I won't...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, that is just a dummy data, the important thing is there should only be one dictionary per 'vidname' as I stack all tensors belonging to the same 'vidname' together

Comment: Then, please make your dummy data *very* simple and easy to read.

Comment: Make a dictionary whose keys are the video names. Use that to combine all the elements for the same video.